# Find the smallest number in sequence fails using loop

Tags: clojure

I am a Clojure beginner and I cannot decode the meaning of the error or understand why it is happening in my small program to find the smallest number in a sequence.

```
(defn find-min
  [nums]
  (loop [smallest 1000000 i 0]
    (if (= (count nums) i)
      smallest)
    (if (< (nums i) smallest)
      (recur (nums i) (inc i))
      (recur smallest (inc i)))))


(find-min [3 4 0 2])
```

IndexOutOfBoundsException   clojure.lang.PersistentVector.arrayFor (PersistentVector.java:158)

Now I do understand that there is an Index out of bound error but the first *if* function takes care that the function returns so why is it happening?

Comment: the first `(if ..)` and second`(if ..)` will both be evaluated. there's no such thing as `return`.

Comment: To clarify what @ymonad said, there is a such thing as `return` but it is implicit and follows a uniform set of rules. It is what makes lisp so powerful but also confusing for beginners. The easiest transition to functional thinking is to think in terms of pipelines.  You want the smallest number in a list. so the first thing is to sort the list. Now the first element of the list is the smallest so get the first element. `(first (sort nums))` Clojure evaluates inside out so the return of sort is passed to first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two `if` are on the same level, so both of them will be executed subsequently. You may want to put the second `if` nested in the first `if`

```
  (defn find-min[nums]
    (loop [smallest 1000000 i 0]
      (if (= (count nums) i)
        smallest
        (if (< (nums i) smallest)
          (recur (nums i) (inc i))
          (recur smallest (inc i))))))
```